# recommended method of configuring access between ec2 and rds instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, amazon-rds

I have created an AWS ec2 instance to operate as a basic webserver.

I also setup an rds instance for a simple database.

How does one make sure that the ec2 instance can connect to the proper database port on the rds instance?

In the ec2 console, I set up a security group that defines the type as MSSQL, port as 1433, and Source as the public IP of my ec2 instance (x.x.x.x/32), but the ec2 instance can't connect to the rds over 1433.

Is there a recommended way of doing this?

thanks

Comment: If they're in the same VPC (likely) you should use the *internal* IP of the EC2 instance.

Comment: @ceejayoz thanks, according to the ec2 and rds consoles, they do run in the same VPC.  Is the internal IP the same as the private IP?  That is the only one I see(along with public).

Comment: Yes, the private IP is what you'll want. Note you can also authorize a *security group*, which may be more resilient - particularly if you're using an auto-scaling group or something that might change your instances' IPs.

Comment: @ceejayoz I tried going into security groups, but aws gives me the 'Your account does not support the EC2-Classic Platform in this region. DB Security Groups are only needed when the EC2-Classic Platform is supported. Instead, use VPC Security Groups ' message...

Comment: Yeah, you'll want to go into the EC2 console to do that.

Comment: @ceejayoz thanks, I think I got it now...how does AWS know that I want to create this security group for the RDS?  The source is the ec2 webserver, but there is no way to specify the destination...

Comment: When you set up the RDS, you will have had to choose or create a security group. That group will be one of your EC2 security groups. They are not RDS-only and can be used for both EC2 and RDS instances - that's an older practice (hence the message you got). Check the RDS console for which security group is being used on your RDS>

Comment: One small question here: if the RDS instance is not in the same VPC as the EC2's, doesn't that imply an additional traffic-between-the-instances cost?

Comment: @Alex Yes, I believe so. You'll definitely want them in the same VPC.